# Creating a mouse drag done observable with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following

```
var leftMouseDown = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(displayCanvas, "MouseLeftButtonDown");
var leftMouseUp = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(displayCanvas, "MouseLeftButtonUp");
var mouseMove = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(displayCanvas, "MouseMove");

var leftMouseDragging = from down in leftMouseDown
                        let startPoint = down.EventArgs.GetPosition(displayCanvas)
                        from move in mouseMove.TakeUntil(leftMouseUp)
                        let endPoint = move.EventArgs.GetPosition(displayCanvas)
                        select new { Start = startPoint, End = endPoint };
```

which when I subscribe to it will give me the start point of the drag and the current end point.  Now I need to do something once the drag is done.  I was unsuccessful in attempting to do this completely with RX and ended up doing

```
leftMouseDragging.Subscribe(value=>
    {
        dragging = true;
        //Some other code
    });

leftMouseUp.Subscribe(e=>
    {
        if(dragging)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Just finished dragging");
            dragging = false;
        }
    });
```

This works fine until I do a right mouse button drag.  Then when I click the left mouse button I get the message box.  If I only do a left button drag I get the message box, and then clicking the left mouse button doesn't produce the box.  I'd like to do this without the external state, but if nothing else I'd at least like for it to work properly.

FYI: I tried making dragging volatile and using a lock, but that didn't work.

**EDIT**

It turns out my problem was with a right click context menu.  Once I got rid of that my above code worked.  So, now my problem is how to I get to have the context menu and still have my code work.  I assume the Context menu was handling the left mouse click and that somehow caused my code to not work, but I'm still puzzling it out.

Comment: I asked a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574046/whats-the-best-way-to-structure-this-linq-to-events-drag-drop-code - does sergey's answer help?

Comment: @Rob that's close, but in my case I don't want to know when they just clicked the mouse without doing a drag where as in your code that would create an ellipse in the location and change it's color.  I'll see if I can incorporate Publish and Connect to get this to work.

Answer (score 5):

If drag is all you need, wouldn't a simple .Zip work? :

```
var drag = _mouseDown
    .Select(args => args.EventArgs.GetPosition(canvas))
    .Zip(_mouseUp.Select(args => args.EventArgs.GetPosition(canvas)), 
        (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 });
drag.Subscribe(p1p2 => 
        Console.WriteLine(@"({0}:{1})({2}:{3})", 
            p1p2.p1.X, p1p2.p1.Y, p1p2.p2.X, p1p2.p2.Y));
```

You can apply Where filter if you need to exclude zero-length drag.

Edit: though, Zip would be vulnerable to releasing the mouse outside the window - in that case, you do not get mouseUp unless you capture...
Here's the version that uses only the latest mouseDown before mouseUp:

```
var drag = _mouseDown
    .Select(args => args.EventArgs.GetPosition(canvas))
    .TakeUntil(_mouseUp)
    .CombineLatest(_mouseUp
        .Select(args => args.EventArgs.GetPosition(canvas))
        .Take(1), (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 })
    .Repeat();
```

Comment: I've been messing with this and I can't seem to figure out what _mouseDown and _mouseUp are in your example. Also, MouseButtonEventArgs does not seem to exist either. Maybe this is just older code examples?